# Why does the barplot2 only color 3/4 bars in R?

Tags: r, gplots

I'm trying to make a barplot2 of a dataset (which is too long to upload) with 4 different colors. The problem is, only 3/4 are colored it skips the first bar. I've searched on Google to check whether I've written it correct or not, but it should be correct. I've also tried to write the colors in numbers instead of names like

```
col = 3:4:5:6
```

But I got the same result, it skips the first bar.

**What I've tried:**
I've looked here on Stackoverflow before asking the question, but I didn't find a solution for my problem, moreover I've also tried Google. As my dataset is too long, I'm only gonna upload the relevant code, which I expect that you prefer :)

```
## Barplot
library(gplots)
CIA <- t.test(tmp3)$conf.int
CIB <- t.test(tmp5)$conf.int
CIC <- t.test(tmp10)$conf.int
CID <- t.test(tmp17)$conf.int
lower <- c(CIA[1], CIB[1], CIC[1], CID[1])
upper <- c(CIA[2], CIB[2], CIC[2], CID[2])

## install.packages( pkgs= "gplots")

barplot2(c(mean3, mean5, mean10, mean17), 
plot.ci = TRUE, ci.l = lower, ci.u = upper, 
col = c("red", "blue", "yellow", "pink"), 
main ="House 3 & 5 overlap", ylim= c(0,6), 
names = c("3","5","10","17"))
```

Result:

[image]

EDIT: Without na's:

[image]

Comment: barplots are for counts not continuous data, use a boxplot or something else

Comment: I am using it to see which houses overlap. As I can see it's house 3,5,17. Can we agree on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** you probably have an `NA` value for the height of your first bar.

With this reproducible example, I can't replicate:

```
library(gplots)
lower <- c(1,2,3,4)
upper <- c(3,4,5,6)

barplot2(c(2,3,4,5),
         plot.ci = TRUE, ci.l = lower, ci.u = upper, 
         col = c("red", "blue", "yellow", "pink"), 
         main ="House 3 & 5 overlap", ylim= c(0,6), 
         names = c("3","5","10","17"))
```

[image]

This is with `gplots` 2.17.0, R-devel.

**However**, if I re-do the plot with an `NA` for the first value, I get very similar results to yours:

```
barplot2(c(NA,3,4,5),
         plot.ci = TRUE, ci.l = lower, ci.u = upper, 
         col = c("red", "blue", "yellow", "pink"), 
         main ="House 3 & 5 overlap", ylim= c(0,6), 
         names = c("3","5","10","17"))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a smart way to upload the dataset?

Comment: well, I think the question has now reduced to "why is my value of `mean3` coming out as `NA`?" -- which is a different question.  Have you read http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ?

Comment: Thanks! The problem was that I forgot to remove the NA's by writing `na.rm=TRUE` in mean3

Comment: Yes, and to honest, I have tried to follow it, the dput(X) shows tooo many numbers, that's why I didn't upload it.

Comment: So, can we agree on that bar 3 and bar 5 overlap, and bar 5 and bar 17 also overlap? Or am I wrong?

Comment: I've edited the question. I've uploaded the barplot without the `NA's` for `mean3`